# Zooming in on an object in a 2D scene?

Tags: c++

Right now, my camera translates to the camera position and then scales by a scale factor.

```
  al_identity_transform(&mTransform);
    al_translate_transform(&mTransform,-mPosition.x, -mPosition.y);
    al_scale_transform(&mTransform,mScale,mScale);
    al_use_transform(&mTransform);
```

So if I have an object at 400,400 and I want to zoom in on it (make 400, 400 the center of the screen), what would I need to do to the camera position and scale each frame? At the moment, simply increasing mScale goes closer and closer to the origin (top left corner of the screen).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screen is **W** wide and **H** tall and the origin is at the upper left hand corner with positive *x* to the right and positive *y* downward, then in order to ensure that a pixel rendered at *(a,b)* is in the center of the screen, you need to translate that point to (**W/2**,**H/2**).  That's pretty easy:

```
al_identity_transform(&mTransform);
al_translate_transform(&mTransform,W/2-a, H/2-b);
```

If you want to zoom in on that point, you have to translate the point to the origin, apply the scale, and then translate the point back to the center of the screen:

```
al_translate_transform(&mTransform,-W/2, -H/2);
al_scale_transform(&mTransform,mScale,mScale);
al_translate_transform(&mTransform, W/2, H/2);
```

Of course, you can combine the first two translations to get:

```
al_identity_transform(&mTransform);
al_translate_transform(&mTransform,-a, -b);
al_scale_transform(&mTransform,mScale,mScale);
al_translate_transform(&mTransform, W/2, H/2);
```

Which says,

1. start with the identity,
2. move point *(a,b)* to the origin,
3. scale around the origin by `mScale`
4. move whatever's at the origin to the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 matrixes : a camera matrix that will convert any point in world space in camera view, and a model matrix that will translate/scale/rotate any object.

The final vertex position equation is then :

camera_matrix*modelview_matrix*Vertex_position (with vertex position being your initial vertex coordinates).

If you want some help to construct your matrixes, I use custom matrixes in my current project. You will find the sources at http://www.github.com/tuxerr/City. The modelview matrix is in matrix4.cpp in src/ and the camera matrix is in scene.cpp in src/.

Good luck :)